# Using results of dns_get_record()

Tags: php, arrays, dns

I have some code that is suppose to be printing the nameservers of a domain. However upon printing them it gives me this:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    ["host"]=>
    string(7) "php.net"
    ["type"]=>
    string(2) "NS"
    ["target"]=>
    string(19) "remote1.easydns.com"
    ["class"]=>
    string(2) "IN"
    ["ttl"]=>
    int(32)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(5) {
    ["host"]=>
    string(7) "php.net"
    ["type"]=>
    string(2) "NS"
    ["target"]=>
    string(19) "remote3.easydns.com"
    ["class"]=>
    string(2) "IN"
    ["ttl"]=>
    int(32)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(5) {
    ["host"]=>
    string(7) "php.net"
    ["type"]=>
    string(2) "NS"
    ["target"]=>
    string(15) "ns2.easydns.com"
    ["class"]=>
    string(2) "IN"
    ["ttl"]=>
    int(32)
  }
  [3]=>
  array(5) {
    ["host"]=>
    string(7) "php.net"
    ["type"]=>
    string(2) "NS"
    ["target"]=>
    string(15) "ns1.easydns.com"
    ["class"]=>
    string(2) "IN"
    ["ttl"]=>
    int(32)
  }
  [4]=>
  array(5) {
    ["host"]=>
    string(7) "php.net"
    ["type"]=>
    string(2) "NS"
    ["target"]=>
    string(19) "remote2.easydns.com"
    ["class"]=>
    string(2) "IN"
    ["ttl"]=>
    int(32)
  }
}
```

I know that's an array however I only want it to print each name server

```
remote2.easydns.com
ns1.easydns.com
ns2.easydns.com
remote1.easydns.com
```

etc.

This is my current code:

```
<?php
$result = dns_get_record("php.net", DNS_NS);
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($result);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Print_r does a pretty similar thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

assuming that your array has the variable name `$array`:

```
foreach($array as $key=>$value){
    echo $value['target'].'<br>';
}
```

Comment: the `host` key will output `php.net` for all results. You want to output the `target` key.

Comment: yeah that was a stupid error. thanks.

Comment: Gosh don't know why I thought that hah. I'm now trying to resolve the hostname to an IP using gethostbyname() however it just prints: pastebin.com/1Gs1kyY4 instead of the full IP. Am I doing something wrong here? pastebin.com/9u5Q9C79

Answer (score 2):

`$result` is an array of results. Iterate through the array and output the `target` key of each subarray.

```
$result = dns_get_record("php.net", DNS_NS);
foreach ($result as $record) {
    echo $record['target'], "\n";
}
```

Comment: Odd, new line doesn't appear to be working, it's all printed on one line.

Comment: new line will print in the source code, not on the screen

Comment: Gosh don't know why I thought that hah. I'm now trying to resolve the hostname to an IP using gethostbyname() however it just prints: http://pastebin.com/1Gs1kyY4 instead of the full IP. Am I doing something wrong here? http://pastebin.com/9u5Q9C79

Comment: Are you going through a Proxy?